# Accessing model attributes in the template in django

Tags: django, forms

this is a snippet of the views.py of my django app.i have used modelform to create a form. the models.py has a class user which has an attibute username. i want to redirect the registration page to a view 'redirect' but also i want to pass the name of the user which is obtained after we hit the submit button on the form and the data gets stored in the instance 'new_form'.

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=userForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name=form.cleaned_data['username']
            new_form=form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('redirect'))
    else:
        form=userForm()
    return render(request,'student/registration.html',{'form':form})
```

my redirect.html looks something like this.

```
<h1>You have signed up.</h1>
<p>hello {{field.name}}</p>
```

but the problem is that name is not being displayed after hello which is obvious because i haven't passed anything with reverse('redirect'). So how do i do that? And is there any problem with my redirect.html also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a context dictionary and send.

```
def registration(request):
    context ={}
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=userForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name=form.cleaned_data['username']
            context['name']=name
            new_form=form.save()

            return render(request,'student/registration.html',context)
    else:
        form=userForm()
        context['form']=form
    return render(request,'student/registration.html',context)
```

Now **html**

```
<h1>You have signed up.</h1>
<p>hello {{name}}</p>
```

Comment: @Shefali, In this way you can send as many fields as you want like  `name`, `form`, `location` and whatever you need just add to **context** dictionary and send.

Comment: `{{field.name }}` will work if you have more than one information in one field like, **user** has name, designation, location. Then you can use `{{user.name}}` and `{{user.designation}}` etc.

Comment: Please vote and select the answer, If it helped your query. Thanks for cooperation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('redirect'))`.

Use `return render(request, 'redirect.html', {'name': name})`.

And edit your `redirect.html` to

```
<h1>You have signed up.</h1>
<p>hello {{name}}</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah that helped...thanks..is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Can you please explain what other way you are asking about?

Comment: something of the sort where we use {{field.name}} in the template...is there any such way or i might have misread somewhere?..